# jquery navigation scroll up on slide, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

any one who have a solution for me why is it not working?
most websites let navigation disappear on slide down and show whe you toggle back up, in my case i tried to insert a Script, and tried not to effect the HTML code and use from what I have, but nothing works.
the Script-

```
<script>
var previousScroll = 0,
headerOrgOffset = $('#header').offset().top;

$('target').height($('#header').height());

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(currentScroll + " and " + previousScroll + " and " + headerOrgOffset);
    if(currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
            $('#header').fadeOut();
        } else {
            $('#header').fadeIn();
            $('#header').addClass('fixed');
        }
    } else {
         $('#header').removeClass('fixed');   
    }
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
</script>
```

The HTML-

```
<nav class="navi" id="target">
    <div class="menu" id="header">

        <li><a class="link-1" href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a class="link-1" href="#">second</a></li>
        <li><a class="link-1" href="#">third</a></li>
        <div class="logo">
        <li><a href="#"><img alt="Brand" src="logo.png" height="40px" width="60px"></a><li>
        </div>

    </div>
<div class="handle"><p>menu</p></div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: can u give example of what u said "most websites"?

Answer (score 1):

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/66jk442L/

here is one way to do it.

```
var timeout,
navbar = $('.navbar'),
    h = navbar.height();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        timeout = setTimeout(hideBar, 1200);
    } else {
        showBar();
    }
});

function showBar() {
    navbar.css('height', h);
    $('.navbar > *').show();
}

function hideBar() {
    $('.navbar > *').hide();
    navbar.css('height', 5);
}

navbar.hover(function () {
    showBar();
}, function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        timeout = setTimeout(hideBar, 1200);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('target').height($('#header').height());
```

change it to

```
$('#target').height($('#header').height());
```

you forgot # :)

Comment: can u add it in jsfiddle i notice it work and the nav was fadeout

Comment: well my friend it is very close but first the nav isnt fully disappearing but only the text. which is nice but still not there, also it takes effect on the media but not in the right way.